# Pop up in website odoo 8

Tags: popup, web, odoo, odoo-8

I need to open a pop up when i click on the link 'Click here to Edit'. [image]

I tried below code

```
@http.route(['/ftp_server/web/edit_dir/'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def edit_dir(self, **kwargs):
    cr, uid, context, pool = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry
    print'ftp_server_kwargs', kwargs

    values = {}
    return request.website.render("website.contentMenu.dialog.edit", values)
```

But getting an error:

```
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: website.contentMenu.dialog.edit
```

I am trying like Edit Menu in website.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need your popup to have a template with the id "edit" and that will only work if that popup is part of the module "website.contentMenu.dialog".

The form is:

```
request.website.render("modulename.templateid", {
 'data_sent_to_template': data_generated_in_controller
}
```

```
<template id="templateid">
   //pop up html
</template>
```

http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/website.html#templates

Generally, in this kind of case,I would prefer to build the popup in html in the page, use jquery to show and hide and Ajax to post it to the controller and get data from it without rendering the data with python.